# How to get basic database information in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress plugin where I'm trying to fetch some basic information about the kind of database installed.

The information I need are as follows:

- Database Software: it can be MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle or anything else
- Database Version: I know how to get it

Now I know I can get the database version easily by running the following query:

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT VERSION() AS version");
```

But I have no idea about how to get the database software name.

Does anyone knows any way to get this details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the tables in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` db with a `use` and `show tables` and poke around.

```
SELECT variable_value 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSION_VARIABLES 
WHERE variable_name IN ('version_comment','version_compile_os','version_compile_machine','version','innodb_version');
+------------------------------+
| variable_value               |
+------------------------------+
| 5.6.31                       |
| Win64                        |
| x86_64                       |
| MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| 5.6.31-log                   |
+------------------------------+
```

MySQL Manual page entitled [Chapter 22 INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html).

Comment: But how am I supposed to know from this whether the user is using default MySQL or MariaDB MySQL drop in or Oracle or something else?

Comment: the strings will confirm that. They like to boast about that in their strings, no?

Comment: What string are you talking about? `version` will say MySQL for both normal MySQL & MariaDB

Comment: can you find one to pick up in `show variables;` among the 500 that spit out?

Comment: according to [this](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-check-the-mysql-version/) it is in a instring search. idk. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was getting this in my end: http://puu.sh/rD4JT/1a05710a7c.png may be because I was coding in localhost.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP if you use PDO driver  you can use can use `PDO::getAttribute()` with `PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME`:

assuming $conn is your connection you can retrive the related db driver  with

```
$dbDriverName = $conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME);
```

you can check if you have the vars

```
 $DB_HOST, 
 $DB_USER, 
 $DB_PASSWORD
 $DB_NAME
```

then you can try a new connection

```
$conn = mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME);
```

or you can import  wp-config.php for get the db connection param  see this for a suggestion  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162614/how-to-make-connection-to-wordpress-data-base-in-a-plugin

Comment: Thanks. This is great for normal PHP script, in WordPress all database calls gets handled by `$wpdb`. So, how should I handle it in WordPress?

Comment: if $wpdb  is the connection try  ..  $wpdb->getAttribute( PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME ); otherwise show  the code where the connection is established

Comment: WordPress handles DB connection via `wp-config.php` you can see more details here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

Comment: Also here is a reference URL for WordPress's `$wpdb` object https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Here is the actual PHP file `wp-db.php` file where the actual connection occurs: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php

Comment: I have added a suggestion .. hope is useful

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I was hoping for more generic approach. I mean what if someone doesn't have PDO installed on their server and still wanna use the plugin.

Comment: But wp use  mysqli_ and mysql_ driver for db and this drivers  .. are for mysql  (and mariadb)  and not for oracle .. if you don't have  PDO you can use only  mysql or mariadb .. so your question can be generically assumed without PDO